# Select only one Item from listView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am beginner in c#.  I need to show only one Item of the `ListView` (with its sub items), when user selects an item name which are populated also in `ComboBox`.

I know the event to use i.e., `SelectedIndexChanged` event. But I dont know what to do in that.

Currently I am using alternative big process which includes XML file and dataset which makes my project more complex.

The `ListView` has many items in it. Same item names are also in `ComboBox`.

If you have time please take a look at my very small project. **[download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87374848/FlagsApp%201001.zip)**

**EDIT**:     Here "*Show only one item*" means strictly show only one item, not select the particular item and show all the items.

Comment: Why the listview has many items in it if you want it to only display one selected from the combobox? Also, showing some code might help.

Comment: When the user selects from the combo, unload the ListView, and reload the same way you already do - but limiting it.  Such as: "If item.Name == comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()"  (pseudocode).

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use this piece of code to get the desired results:

**ADDED:**

Follow these steps:

1. Create a Country class as follows:

   ```
   class Country
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Flag { get; set; }
       public string Continent { get; set; }
       public string Capital { get; set; }
       public string Population { get; set; }
       public string Currency { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Populate the countries information as per your requirement, as shown below:

   ```
   List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>() { 
       new Country() { Name = "India", Capital = "Delhi", Continent = "Asia", Currency = "Rupee", Population = "1.2 Billion", Flag = "india.gif" }, 
       new Country() { Name = "Pakistan", Capital = "Islamabad", Continent = "Asia", Currency = "Rupee", Population = "0,5 Billion", Flag = "pakistan.gif" }, 
       new Country() { Name = "Sri Lanka", Capital = "Kotte", Continent = "Asia", Currency = "SriLankan Rupee", Population = "20277597", Flag = "sri_lanka.gif" } 
   };
   ```
3. Modify *frmFlag_Load* event as shown below:

   ```
   private void frmFlag_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lvMain.Items.Clear();
       tlstrpcmbCountries.Items.Clear();

       tlstrpcmbCountries.Items.Add("All");
       for (int i = 0; i < countryList.Count; i++)
       {
           tlstrpcmbCountries.Items.Add(countryList[i].Name);
       }

       tlstrpcmbCountries.SelectedIndex = 0;
       tlstrpcmbViews.SelectedIndex = 0;
   }
   ```
4. Modify the *SelectedIndexChanged* event of your *ComboBox* and *ListView* as shown below:

   ```
   private void tlstrpcmbCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var country = countryList.Where(c => c.Name.Equals(tlstrpcmbCountries.SelectedItem.ToString())).Select(s => s).FirstOrDefault();

       if (country != null)
       {
           lvMain.Items.Clear();

           ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(country.Name, country.Flag);

           item.SubItems.Add(country.Continent);
           item.SubItems.Add(country.Capital);
           item.SubItems.Add(country.Population);
           item.SubItems.Add(country.Currency);
           lvMain.Items.Add(item);

           lvMain.EnsureVisible(0);
           item.Selected = true;
           item.Focused = true;
           lvMain.Select();
       }
   }

   private void lvMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (lvMain.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
       {
           var selected = lvMain.SelectedItems[0];
           lblCountryName.Text = selected.SubItems[0].Text;
           lblContinent.Text = selected.SubItems[1].Text;
           lblCapitalCity.Text = selected.SubItems[2].Text;
           lblPopulation.Text = selected.SubItems[3].Text;
           lblCurrencyName.Text = selected.SubItems[4].Text;
       }
   }
   ```

By following this approach, you don't even need to match the order your items.

Happy Coding...

Comment: yes i have same items.. items has same names with also case-sensitive

Comment: The list view has many items in it from before only, i need to show only one item by hiding all other items or removing them temporarily or some how. This also not working. I will share my small project with you wait.

Comment: no still not. Is the code which i have shared is working with this technique?

Comment: Yes, it working at my side perfectly. The only problem is the items are not in order as i mentioned in my answer. Check for the correct event handler. I changed ListView_Click event handler to ListView_SelectedIndexChanged. Make sure this is correct at your side

Comment: I corrected the orders.. still it is just selecting the particular item and showing all the items :( . I have not done any edits in my code also. Can you give me that working project?

Comment: I have provided you the code i changed. No other changes. You are saying it is selecting the particular item then what is still wrong?

Comment: It shouldnt select the item. It should show the only item and hide other items(or remove it or anything else). If my question is not clear then I apologize for that. Please edit my question so that it should be more understandeable (i am bit poor in english).. if you want to.

Comment: With this much dedicated support i expect a little bit of appreciation.

Comment: +1 well you are right. sorry i have not considered your efforts. I was here busy to get that answer. Anyhow if I get the answer, I will share here.

Comment: Yes alot in many ways but not to this question :( thats why I just upvoted it. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many attempts I settled with using `DataSet` or `DataTable` because here we need to save the changes made to the list view items and those changes should be saved in `DataSet` or `DataTable` so that those items can recall later.